# Saving an ArrayList of custom objects to user settings

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, settings

Is it possible to save an ArrayList of custom objects to the application user settings without resorting to custom serialization?

For example, given a basic data class containing only public get/set properties and private backing fields:

```
[Serializable]
class SimpleClass()
{
  ...   
}
```

When I run the following in code, and then restart the application, the ArrayList setting named MyList is always null, ie it was not saved.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.MyList==null)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.MyList=new ArrayList();
}

Properties.Settings.Default.MyList.Add(new SimpleClass(DateTime.Now.ToString()));

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I realise that an ArrayList is not typed, ie. it holds a collection of objects.  However it is simple to use GetType() on each object to determine the actual type.  This should allow serialization to occur, shouldn't it?

I also know how to get around this performing some custom serialization.  It's just a pain this doesn't appear to work as it would be by far the most convenient for simpler situations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XML Serialization, you can use the XmlArrayItem attribute.

```
 [XmlArray("Items")]
 [XmlArrayItem("A.Thing",typeof(Thing))]
 [XmlArrayItem("A.Different.Thing",typeof(Whatzit))]
 public System.Collections.ArrayList List;
```

This requires that you know the different types that may be present in the ArrayList at compile time.